# Why won't my thread stop running after it is done?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, object, thread-safety

I have a program that is supposed to sort different strings in different arrays. The program itself almost works, but there is a certain part of the program that will not stop running. In the run method, the threads will not stop running after sorting it's content.

If I for instance create 4 threads, that are supposed to sort an array of 10 words each. The programming will keep on running after the 4th array and 40th word are running.

### run (in a class called threads)

```
public void run(){

    try{
        sortArray();

        while(monitor.tabStorrelse1() == uTabell.length || monitor.tabStorrelse2() == uTabell.length){
            if(monitor.returTab1() != null && monitor.returTab2() != null){
                String[] tab1 = monitor.returTab1();
                String[] tab2 = monitor.returTab2();

                if(tab1 != null && tab2 != null){
                    monitor.tomTab1(); //method that clears arrays
                    monitor.tomTab2();
                }

                String[] totalTab = new String[tab1.length + tab2.length];
                int b = 0;
                int c = 0;
                int d = 0;
                while(b < tab1.length && c < tab2.length ){ //this merges 2 sorted arrays, into one sorted array
                    if(tab1[b].compareTo(tab2[c]) < 0){
                        totalTab[d] = tab1[b];
                        b++;
                    } else {
                        totalTab[d] = tab2[c];
                        c++;
                    }
                    d++;
                }

                while(b < tab1.length){
                    totalTab[d] = tab1[b];
                    b++;
                    d++;
                }

                while(c < tab2.length) {
                    totalTab[d] = tab2[c];
                    c++;
                    d++;
                }
                monitor.putIn(totalTab);

            }
        }

    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The sortArray method just sorts it, I believe that the problem lies in the run, or how my program is executing some of the methods.

```
public synchronized void putIn(String[] tabellFraTraad){

  if(tabell1 == null && tabell2 == null){
    tabell1 = tabellFraTraad;
    notify();
  }
  else if(tabell1 != null && tabell2 == null){
    tabell2 = tabellFraTraad;
    notify();
  }
  else if(tabell1 != null && tabell2 != null){
    try{
      wait();
    }catch(InterruptedException err){
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

not sure if notify is right.

Comment: Either it is done or it doesn't stop running. Not both at the same time. Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: a Thread dump could help

Comment: Is it getting stuck in a loop?

Comment: please provide the thread dump